# How to take only 3 duplicates from a list with 6 or more duplicates and put them in another list

Tags: python, counter

I made some code that solve my problem, but it's to slow. Any others solutions?

Input

```
['13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780']
```

```
bs = []
ls = []
for item in append_to_table2:
    counted = Counter(ls)
    if counted[item] <= 2:
        ls.append(item)
    else:
        bs.append(item)
print(ls)
```

Output

```
['13906577679124', '13906577679124', '13906577679124', '142404643442629780', '142404643442629780', '142404643442629780']
```

Comment: What is `ls`? Please add input and expected output

Comment: it seems ` counted = Counter(ls)` could be done outside of the loop to not compute it each time. What is `append_to_table2` ?

Comment: Help us help you - can you share a sample input and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: ls and bs are empty lists. In append_to_table2 data like [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,6,6,6,6,]

Comment: What are `append_to_table2`  and  `Counter(ls)` ? What do you need to do in this code ?

Comment: you need to edit your question with code to show what the missing variables or functions are, see how to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can count just once and then compare:

```
d = {}  
ls = []  
cnt = 0    # to count the length of ls  
for item in append_to_table2:  
    d[item] = d.get(item,0)+1  

for item in d:  
     if d[item]>1:  
         ls.append(item)  
         cnt+=1  
     if cnt == 3:  
         break
```

Comment: might be worthwhile to answer the OP using the `Counter` container from the built-in library rather than counting it literally, unless there are other advantages (i.e. performance, memory, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list comprehension on the old list with a condition on the counted items... like so...

```
bs=[i for i in append_to_table2 if counted[i] > 2]
print(bs)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I might have misunderstood the question but according to me what I'm trying to is any element whose count is less then 3 is appended that many times to ls list and then any element whose count is greater then 3 I'm storing 3 occurences of that list to ls and the rest to bs list

```
from collections import Counter 
from itertools import repeat
org=['13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','13906577679124','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780','142404643442629780']
append_to_table2=list(set(org))
bs = []
ls = []
for item in append_to_table2:
    ele_count = org.count(item)
    if ele_count<= 2:
        ls.extend(repeat(item, ele_count)) 
    else:
        left=ele_count-3
        ls.extend(repeat(item, 3))
        bs.extend(repeat(item, left))
print(ls)
```

Output:

```
['13906577679124', '13906577679124', '13906577679124', '142404643442629780', '142404643442629780', '142404643442629780']
```

I'm also new so any suggestions to improve the code will be very much appreciable

Answer (score 0):

This is your code just condensed and optimized further.

```
bs = []
ls = []

[ls.append(item) if Counter(ls)[item] <= 2 else bs.append(item) for item in append_to_table2]

print(ls)
```